# Can the future affect the past in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, causality

Hypothetically, let us suppose that a black hole were to suddenly appear at time $t=1$ at position $x$. Can the effect of the black hole be felt at time $t = 1-\epsilon$ near $x$ due to the bending of space-time by the black hole?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question so that it's asking about something that's physically possible? General relativity doesn't answer questions about scenarios that require magic: changes can be very fast, but they have to be smooth. Blatant discontinuities are impossible.

Comment: PM 2Ring's comment is the essential one, but I would also point out that a black hole singularity is a spacelike singularity, not a timelike one, and a black hole's event horizon is null, not timelike. So if the question is referring to the singularity, then in fact that *is* sort of how it behaves in real life: the singularity does "suddenly appear," in the sense that we can make a spacelike surface very close to the singularity. Also, if we want to rule out the sudden appearance of a black hole without gravitational collapse, the reason it's forbidden is more like conservation of ADM mass.

Comment: If you take unrealistic initial conditions, the equations of General Relativity would produce unrealistic results. The same is true in any field of physics.

Comment: @safesphere: Aren't his initial conditions just Minkowski space? Nothing realistic about that.

Comment: Do you allow [CTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve)s?

Comment: @BenCrowell No, his initial conditions are a black hole that instantly appears out of nowhere, which is unrealistic. I see your point that *the singularity does "suddenly appear"*. However, it doesn't suddenly appear in the Minkowski spacetime, but in the spacetime already defined by the future singularity (plus only either naked or inside the horizon). So this is not the same as a black hole suddenly appearing out of nowhere in a previously undisturbed region of spacetime. At least, I don't think this is what the OP means in his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The bending of spacetime itself propagates at the speed of light so a nearby observer would not experience the sudden appearance of gravity sooner than (s)he could detect the black hole's appearance with a telescope.

That said, note that per Ben Crowell's comment below, it isn't possible in the first place to make a black hole or any other chunk of mass appear suddenly from out of nowhere.

Comment: The OP postulates things that contradict GR (a black hole that "suddenly appears") and then asks what GR predicts. You can't answer that question withing the logical framework of GR.

Comment: @bencrowell, ok- the question is ill-posed. but is it not still true than anything having to do with a large gravitational event- like for example the merging of two orbiting neutron stars into a black hole- cannot outrace a light beam produced in that same event?

Comment: If a star (or a black hole ) moving for a long time with the same speed passes by the Earth at a distance, of, say, 10 light minutes, then the Earth would be attracted to the present position of the star, but not to the star's retarded position of where it was 10 minutes ago where we would see it.

Comment: However, if a sudden event happens producing both light and gravitational waves, then gravity would not outtrace light.

Answer (score 2):

Technically: in general relativity, if there there exist a [Cauchy hypersurface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) (that is, a subset of space-time which is intersected by every inextensible, non-spacelike (i.e. causal) curve exactly once) then the spacetime is [globally hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold). That means there is a homeomorphism from the spacetime manifold $M$ to $S \times \mathbb{R}$ where $S$ is the 3D Cauchy hypersurface ([Geroch 1970](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1665157)).

Less technically: if there are Cauchy hypersurfaces - a generalisation of "an instant of time" that can be extended everywhere - then spacetime behaves as the product of the shape it has on the surface and some time coordinate.

At the very least this rules out making closed causal curves since there is a well-defined time direction. Sudden appearances of things that change the topology of spacetime are also banned.

Global hyperbolicity ensures predictability. A system is "predictable" if its state on a Cauchy surface uniquely determines its state at any future point. A physical theory is "prognostic" if all systems described by the theory are predictable. Theories such as relativistic mechanics and electrodynamics are prognostic theories on globally hyperbolic manifolds. If predictability does not hold then the extra information needed to determine the state at a point needs to either "come out of nowhere" somehow, or arrive along spacelike curves implying superluminal information transfer. Conversely, prognostic theories do not allow superluminal signals. For globally hyperbolic spacetimes and predictable matter fields general relativity is prognostic: the metric of spacetime is uniquely determined by the field equations and knowing it on a Cauchy surface ([Hawking 1973](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/large-scale-structure-of-spacetime/1E6B961EC9878EDDBBD6AC0AF031CC93),[Krasnikov 2006](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0302107)).

Comment: Anders, does nonprognostic also mean acausal, or how should that be defined?

Comment: @nielsnielsen - I think acausal is used in many ways, but a common interpretation in GR is spacetimes that have closed timelike curves (CTCs). Predictability prevents acausality in this sense, and prognostibility hence also does. But nonprognostic physics might not be so bad that it causes CTCs, so it does not imply acausality.

Comment: Got it, tak for det. -NN